# Ruby on rails Association Records returns empty But in rails console it returns something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

in the registration.rb

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
......
has_many :cash_transactions

after_destroy :destroy_cash_transaction

def first_cash_transaction
  self.cash_transactions.first
end

def destroy_cash_transaction
  if first_cash_transaction.registrations.count == 0
   self.cash_transactions.find(first_cash_transaction).destroy
  end
end
```

in cashtransaction.rb

```
class CashTransaction< ActiveRecord::Base
......
has_many :registrations
```

so, when I destory the registration, it will destroy_cash_transaction associated with the registration.

In the rails console, I tried:

```
Registration.find(some_id).cash_transactions
```

The console returns some records

However, when I tried to delete a registration, it will invoke destroy_cash_transaction, which will call first_cash_transaction, which returns  empty records.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

-----updated------

in participant controller

```
 def destroy
  if @registration.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to admin_events_participants_path, :notice => "#{@registration.email}'s registration has been deleted."}
   end
  else
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
     flash[:warning] = print_out_message('form-destroy','registration')
     redirect_to admin_events_participants_path 
    }
   end
  end

def load_registration
  @registration = @event.registrations.find(params[:registration_id])
 end
```

Comment: Are you trying to get `first_cash_transaction` of a the same `Registration` which you verified that have a transaction in console ? Can you post where and how are you calling `first_cash_transcation` method ?

Comment: Again you are not showing where are you using this `destroy_cash_transaction` and this confuse me a little . And I think you have created `first_cash_transaction` as model instance method so It should be used on a object like `@registration.first_cash_transaction`.

Comment: the destroy_cash_transaction function is in registration.rb.  first_cash_transaction is also a method in registration.rb. So when I destroy a registration, it will invoke destroy_cash_transaction, which invoke first_cash_transaction

Comment: when you destroy a registration, how it will invoke `destroy_cash_transaction` ? Have you written anything for it because I am not sure that rails provide any such feature automatically or I am missing something.

Comment: that is because, in the registration model, I have set after_destroy :destroy_cash_transaction

Comment: Can you put some log of when rails executes `self.cash_transactions.first` ? or try to put `byebug` in this method and be sure that it references the `self` correctly and fires correct query.

Comment: i found the reason, it is due to any attribute which has dependency on delete. so regiatration cannot return anything. if i remove the dependent on delete condition, everything goes correcrly

Comment: You're looking for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association there, by the looks.